# p-any versus Promise.any

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

## Problem

The [p-any](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-any) package suggests that it is a replacement for `Promise.race` given this [link](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.race.html) as a reason. As `p-any` suggest, it does seem it like is a better option in most scenarios, however `Promise.any` seems to do the same thing.

### My understanding

`Promise.race` takes an `Iterable` of promises and returns the first promise that completes with either an error or resolution.

`Promise.any` returns the first promise that resolves, and ignores failures.

### Help

Is my understanding correct? Do `p-any` and `Promise.any` do the same thing? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is whether `p-any`'s `any` function and the standard `Promise.any` function do the same thing, then based on `p-any`'s documentation, yes, they do. They both get fulfilled when the first promise from the iterable gets fulfilled, or get rejected with an `AggregateError` if all of the promises from the iterable get rejected.

`Promise.any` is still just a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-any), though it's likely to hit Stage 4 very soon. `p-any` and similar presumably predate that effort slightly.

This chart *(I wish SO's markdown allowed tables!)* may be useful for understanding the different Promise combinators:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Name               | Description                                     | Added In         |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Promise.allSettled | does not short−circuit                          | ES2020           |
| Promise.all        | short−circuits when an input value is rejected  | ES2015           |
| Promise.race       | short−circuits when an input value is settled   | ES2015           |
| Promise.any        | short−circuits when an input value is fulfilled | Stage 3 proposal |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

[This article](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators) the proposal links to may as well.

Comment: Hi, is it possbile to polyfill Promise.any for "old" browers ? I tried but failed.

Comment: @Qiulang - Yes, all of the promise combinators can be polyfilled. There are [lots of polyfills for `Promise.any`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Promise.any%22+polyfill), including ones from [`es-shims`](https://github.com/es-shims/Promise.any) and [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.promise.any.js).

Comment: I have not been able to make it work. Maybe you can check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044132/is-it-possible-to-break-away-from-await-promise-all-when-any-promise-has-fulfill

Comment: I did manage to upgrade babel7 but now even my chrome 88 failed to work for Promise.any() I have gave up.